# scrollIntoView is not working on chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to show the element on screen completely when the focus is on the element. I am using scrollIntoView as when i focus into my search box using TABS i am seeing only truncated search box. To make it visible completely i am using scrollIntoView. But it is working fine in FIREFOX and IE,EDGE but not in chrome. See the code below

Code:

```js
this._searchbox = document.createElement("INPUT")
.addClass('SearchBox')
.focus(function () {
  $(this).parent().get(0).scrollIntoView();
});
```

I am using parent to focus because i want to show the whole parent for which the search box is child. That is my requirement.The parent is div element FYI.

Comment: Based on your code, you are only creating the element and not appending it to the document (body). You can't focus on something that doesn't yet exist. Can you provide a demo illustrating the issue? Also please note, [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) is an experimental technology. Here is a table with what browsers currently support it - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I havent given complete code, I have just given code where i am using scrollIntoView

Comment: @Dom can you suggest any other replacement for scrollintoview with out any external plugin needed i am currently using JQuery and React

Comment: would you mind providing a demo with your react/jquery code?